# Using a slider to change variable and replot Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

I'm trying to use a slider to change the limits for color scaling i.e using the set_clim(min,max) function. I want it so that two sliders control the values for the min and max values and after they have changed the figure is replotted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
y=np.linspace(0,100,100)
z=np.zeros((100,100))
for i in range (0,100):
    for j in range (0,100):
        z[i,j]=np.random.random()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
l=plt.contourf(x,y,z)

axmax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
axmin  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])

smax = Slider(axmax, 'Max', 0, 1.0, valinit=1)
smin = Slider(axmin, 'Min', 0, 1.0, valinit=0)
def update(val):
    fig.set_clim(smin.val,smax.val)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
smax.on_changed(update)
smin.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

The above code gives me " AttributeError: 'AxesSubPlot' object has no attribute 'set_clim' " when I move the sliders although it does show me the initial unchanged figure. This is my first time using widgets in python (and more or less my first time using python) so there may well be some quite fundamental misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as the error tells you, `axes` objects don't have a `set_clim` function.  You want to change (which makes the error you report on the one I expect, but)

```
fig.set_clim(smin.val,smax.val)
```

to

```
l.set_clim(smin.val,smax.val)
```

as you need to call `set_clim` on a `ScalarMappable` object [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable).

As a side note, `np.random.random` takes a size arguement so you can do

```
z = np.random.random((100, 100))
```

instead of your nested loops.

Comment: +1 to using the `size` arg to get rid of those loops